# Push array to existing Firestore document

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to push an array with downloadUrl's from Firebase storage to my Firestore document. When I use the code below I only get an empty array (matrix) object in Firestore, see image in attachment.

[Empty Firestore array (matrix) object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjGEE.png)

My current code (added after the document in Firestore is created)

```
this.docRef = docRef.id;
this.houseRef = this.afs.collection('houses').doc(this.docRef);

  if (this.filesToUpload && this.filesToUpload.length) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++) {
      console.log("Adding photo's" + this.filesToUpload[i]);
      const filePath = 'images/' + docRef.id + '/' + i + '.jpg';
      const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      // const task = ref.put(this.imagePaths[i], metadata).then((snapshot) => {
      const task = ref.put(this.filesToUpload[i]).then((snapshot) => {
        // const task = ref.put(imageBlob).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('Uploaded an image!');


        const downloadUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log("downloadURL: " + downloadUrl);
        this.images.push(String(downloadUrl));


      });
    }
    this.imagesArray = this.images.map((obj) => { return Object.assign({}, obj) });
    this.houseRef.update({'images': this.imagesArray});
  }
```

I would like to add an Array in my current Firestore document that looks like this:

```
images: {
  image0: {
      downloadUrl: "path to firebase storage's downloadUrl"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why I keep asking questions, because I always end up having to answer my own eventually. But for anybody who is having the same problem, I fixed it using Firestore transactions.

My current code:

```
this.afs.firestore.runTransaction((t) => {
              return t.get(firebaseRef).then((doc) => {
                // doc doesn't exist; can't update
                if (!doc.data().images2) {
                  console.log("if images2 not found");
                  t.set(firebaseRef, { 'images2': [imageData] }, { merge: true });
                } else {
                  console.log("If images2 found");
                  //const newImagesArray = doc.get('images2').push( {downloadUrl: url} );
                  const existingImages = doc.data().images2;
                  existingImages.push(imageData);
                  t.set(firebaseRef, { images2: existingImages }, { merge: true });
                }
              });
            }).then(function () {
              console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
            }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
            });
```

I hope it helps.